# how to reset the phone pc after too mant pattern attempts

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery

How can I reset my android phone HTC desire HD after too many attempts. I want to reset my phone via connecting it to PC . I don't know how reset it from PC and even I can't reset it from buttons because volume buttons are broken.

Now please somebody tell me how can I reset it from PC.

Comment: I see you've got a big problem and are "bold" enough to ask it – but that shouldn't end up in all-bold-letters, please :) Bold is for emphasis – and emphasizing the entire post makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, most of them requiring [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) being available on your computer:

- [How can i do factory reset using adb in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14685721/2533433) gives this solution:

  ```
  adb shell
  recovery --wipe_data
  ```
- [How to Hard Reset or Factory Reset and Format Android Phones and Tablets](http://www.theandroidsoul.com/how-to-hard-reset-or-factory-reset-and-format-an-android-phones-and-tablets-54113/?PageSpeed=noscript) gives detailed instructions on doing this with `fastboot` (including setting up your computer for that). The command finally doing the job is:

  ```
  fastboot erase userdata
  ```

Doing that, I'd recommend to also include a `fastboot fastboot erase cache` (`recovery --wipe_cache` if you use the first approach).

If you had setup other means of accessing your device's command line interface from your computer (e.g. SSH), you can use the first command (`recovery --wipe_data`) from that shell as well – without the need of ADB/Fastboot.